# Чтение из .dbf с заданной кодировкой

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

При попытке считать.dbf файл с настройкой системы C*ontrol Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Region Settings = "English (UK)"* русские символы считываются в не известной кодировке. Но если данную опцию переключить *Region Settings = "Russian (Russia)"*, то символы считываюся корректно. Варианты, которые я попробовал:

1. Изменять строку подключения с 
   `private const string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE; Data Source={0};";` на `private const string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='dBASE IV;characterset=1251;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'; Data Source={0};";`, но это не помогло.
2. Использовать метод декодирования

   ```
   private string Decode(string input)
   {
       Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp850");
       Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);

       string returnValue = toEncoding.GetString(fromEncoding.GetBytes(input));

       return returnValue;
   }
   ```
3. Использование [FoxPro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) (но данный вариант мне не подходит)

**Мне помог вариант - 2, использование явного декодирования. Хотелось бы знать, могу я как-то в настройках класса "OleDbConnection" или еще каким-нибудь способом явно задать кодировку, которую я ожидаю?**

- Вот пример полученной строки из .dbf файла - ÇóÔ«¡«¼¡Ù® «¬ÓÒú.
- [DBF файл](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PAzk69CyVpyX-apdSHcMVHpnDR_yYFuD)

Пример класса:

```
class DbfReader
    {
        private const string COUNT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "count";
        private const string ROW_ELEMENT_NAME = "r";
        private const string MappedTableName = "SOCRBASE";
        private static string TableName = "socrbase";
        private const string SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties='dBASE IV;characterset=1251;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'; Data Source={0};";

        private static string GetCountQuery = $"select count(1) from [{TableName}]";
        private static string SelectQuery => $"select [{"level"}], [{"scname"}], [{"socrname"}], [{"kod_t_st"}] from [{TableName}]";
        private static List<string> Columns = new List<string> { "level", "scname", "socrname", "kod_t_st" };


        public void Convert(string dataSourceFolder)
        {
            using (var srcConn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(SOURCE_CONNECTION_STRING, dataSourceFolder)))
            {
                srcConn.Open();
                Exception exception = null;

                try
                {
                    var xmlFilePath = GetTableFileName(dataSourceFolder, TableName);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlFilePath));
                    var xml = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
                    xml.WriteStartDocument();
                    var reader = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, srcConn).ExecuteReader();

                    xml.WriteStartElement(MappedTableName);
                    xml.WriteAttributeString(COUNT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ((int)new OleDbCommand(GetCountQuery, srcConn).ExecuteScalar()).ToString());
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        xml.WriteStartElement(ROW_ELEMENT_NAME);
                        foreach (var column in Columns)
                        {
                            xml.WriteStartElement(column);
                            var value = reader[column].ToString();
                            xml.WriteCData(value);
                            xml.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                        xml.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    xml.WriteEndElement();
                    xml.WriteEndDocument();
                    xml.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetTableFileName(string dataSourceFolder, string tableName)
        {
            return Path.Combine(dataSourceFolder, "xml", $"{tableName}.xml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: В строке подключения используете `characterset=1251` в методе декодирования `cp850` & `866`? Так какая же кодировка вам нужна? Для построения строки подключения в ADO.NET есть [строители строки подкючения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders) в соотв. свойстве можно задать кодировку. И по поводу вашего кода: куда проще создать класс сущности, кот.храниться в таблице БД, прочитать всю таблицу в коллекцию этих сущностей, а затем эту коллекцию сериализовать в xml буквально одной строкой кода.

Comment: @Bulson, данный вариант строки подключения является демонстрационным и какие бы значения я не передавал в параметр characterset на результат это не влияет. По поводу декодирования, я привел пример того, что при использовании декодирования из "cp850" в 866 я получаю корректные данные, но это при учете что в региональных настройках стоит UK, если я задам RUSSIAN, то я получу в результате декодирования "???????????" Также я не нашел соотвествующего свойства для того чтобы задать нужную мне кодировку.

Comment: @Bulson, по поводу класса сущностей, мне не совсем ясно. Приведенный код является демонстрационным и какая разница где хранить сущности, если при считывании данных из .dbf файла, я получаю не верную кодировку в зависимости от региональных настроек? Был бы признателен за демонстрационный вариант или подробное объяснение.

Comment: Чтоб написать код, требуется .dbf с такой же кодировкой как и у вас, где взять такую?

Comment: @Bulson, в описании, есть файл "Вот пример полученной строки из .dbf файла - ÇóÔ«¡«¼¡Ù® «¬ÓÒú.

DBF файл"